# Remove pattern from database

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with over 3 million rows that includes peoples names and the state they are from e.g. "Smith (SC)"  I would like to remove the state info and have "Smith".  Since there are many difference last names and states used I was wondering if there was any trick to make this easier and just remove the parentheses and the text contained inside of them.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with a select to make sure you're getting good results:

```
SELECT LastName, LEFT(LastName, LOCATE('(', LastName) - 1) AS CorrectedLastName
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE LOCATE('(', LastName) <> 0
```

Once you're confident in the results:

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET LastName = LEFT(LastName, LOCATE('(', LastName) - 1)
    WHERE LOCATE('(', LastName) <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup first, then try

```
Update <tablename>
 set name =substr(name,1, instr(name,'('));
```

substr is for oracle but check the mysql equivalent

Comment: @Johan: You've got your `locate` syntax reversed. The string you're searching for comes first.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli and Trevor: In MySQL this would be: `Update <tablename> set name = substring(name,1, locate('(',name));`